# Xpath to Scrape Size Information with Scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I aim to scrape the following bit of code:

```
 Select Size:</b>
          <select name="option[225]">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
                        <option value="480">UK 11                        </option>
                        <option value="478">UK 8                        </option>
                        <option value="477">UK 7                        </option>
                      </select>
```

I'm facing two problems:
1) the value in "option[225] isn't constant for all the pages on that site and changes from each product.

2) Is there anyway, I can store the data with semi-colon separators between each value.
I wish for the data to be displayed in the following manner:

```
UK 11;UK 8;UK 7
```

Comment: It should be possible to loop through all of the <option> tags for a particular @name. Please show your working Spider code (with a valid test URL) so that we can better assist. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> ';'.join(map(str.strip, sel.xpath('//option[string-length(@value)!=0]/text()')))
'UK 11;UK 8;UK 7'
```

`//` for selecting all `option` tags starting from the root of the document, `string-length` to filter out first empty name option and `';'.join(...)` to join generator elements with `;` between them

Answer (score 1):

If "Select Size:" is something that is constant before the `select/option`s you want to select, you can try an XPath expression like this:

```
xpath_expression = """//b[contains(., "Select Size:")]
                       /following-sibling::select[starts-with(@name, "option[")][1]
                           /option[@value != ""]/@value"""
```

Then, as @Guy suggests, you can use:

```
    u";".join([val.strip() for val in sel.xpath(xpath_expression).extract()])
```